zalaligne with doublebar not working in Gregorian Chant musixgre library
It is needed to code the "Ubi Caritas est vera" Gregorian Chant using Musixtex with musixgre library, but the zalaligne with doublebar is not working (it is needed left align). The basic code is as follow:
\documentclass[%
border={2pt 7pt 2pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\input musixlit
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{U-bi cá-ri-tas est ve-ra, De-us i-bi est. Con-gre-gá-vit nos in u-num Chris-ti a-mor. Ex-sul-té-mus et in i-pso iu-cun-dé-mur. Ti-me-ám-us et a-mé-mus De-um vi-vum. Et ex cor-de di-li-gá-mus nos {\hspace{-0.5cm}sin}-{cé}-ro.}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
%\parindent0mm
%\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}
\nobarnumbers
\setlines14
\setclef1{4000}
\setstaffs11
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf\medtype \kern0.3pt\raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-\kern0.3pt}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.16pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.16pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance) 
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-4pt\pt {#1}\kern4pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
%\newcommand{\caeg}{\zcharnote{5}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%Barra Vertical
%\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.295) -- ++(0,0.15); %
%\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote{b}{\kern-4.1pt$\A\textbf\shortmid$\kern4.1pt}\hbsk}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\dsbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid\hspace{-0.125cm}\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\A\textbf\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\squ{MM}\podatus{N}{a}\clivis{a}{N}\squ{a}\squ{_b}\clivis{a}{N}\usttt a\clivis{a}{N}\caeg%
\squ{MMMN}\ptt N\squ{N}\en\setdoublebar\bar%\dsbr%%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\squ{MM}\podatus{N}{a}\clivis{a}{N}\squ{a}\squ{_b}\clivis{a}{N}\usttt a\clivis{a}{N}\caeg%
\squ{MMN}\ptt N\squ{N}\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{MM}\podatus{N}{a}\clivis{a}{N}\squ{a}\squ{_b}\clivis{a}{N}\usttt a\clivis{a}{N}\caeg%
\squ{MMN}\ptt N\squ{N}\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{MNM}\podatus{N}{a}\squ{aM}\clivis{N}{M}\usttt K\clivis{K}{J}%
\squ{NaN}\ptt M\squ{M}\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{MNM}\podatus{N}{a}\squ{aM}\clivis{N}{M}\usttt K\clivis{K}{J}%
\squ{N}\tristropha{N}{a}{N}\Porrectus{M}{K}{M}\ptt M\squ{M}\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zstoppiece
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\end{document}

The current output is as follow:

The expected output should be:



Don't start Gregorian chant with a startrule!
If you want music left aligned, don't musixflx.
You are working in a format, which limits the \hsize to the necessary space for the text or music inserted. If you want to have more space at the end, you need to enter \notes\sk\sk\en% (any amount you want) after the \doublebar, which you don't need to "set", because in this case you do not say \alaligne.
Don't align text manually as you did with your last word, unless you have solved all the other alignment problems, including the spacing related to hyphenation!


Solved:
\documentclass[%
border={2pt -9pt 2pt -7pt},% left bottom right top
%border=8pt
varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{scalerel}%Escalar símbolos
\usepackage{musixtex}
\input musixlyr
\input musixlit
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{amssymb}% %$\shortmid$ and $\mid$
\usepackage{xcolor}
\xdefinecolor{red-undar}{RGB}{179,35,79}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lilyglyphs}
\begin{document}
\begin{music}
\hsize=0.92\linewidth%
\resetlyrics
\setlyrics{Letras}{U-bi cá-ri-tas est ve-ra, De-us i-bi est. Con-gre-gá-vit nos in u-num Chris-ti a-mor. Ex-sul-té-mus et in i-pso iu-cun-dé-mur. Ti-me-ám-us et a-mé-mus De-um vi-vum. Et ex cor-de di-li-gá-mus nos {\hspace{-0.5cm}sin}-{cé}-ro.}%
\setsongraise{1}{0.15cm}
\font\A=phvb8t at 8pt% added for letter type.
\font\B=phvb8t at 13pt% added for letter type.
%\parindent0mm
%\sepbarrules
\instrumentnumber{1}
\nobarnumbers%
\nostartrule%
\setlines14%
\setclef1{4000}%
\setstaffs11%
\setaltoclefsymbol1\gregorianCclef%
\newcommand{\ustt}[1]{\raisebox{0.2\Interligne}{\kern-1.4pt \ust {#1}\kern1.4pt}}% normal size \ust centered and put higher for notes on a line
%
\newcommand{\usttt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf\medtype \kern0.3pt\raisebox{0.1\Interligne}-\kern0.3pt}}% shorter \ust
%
\newcommand{\btt}[1]{\zcharnote {#1}{\A\textbf{\kern1.16pt \raisebox{-0.9\Interligne}{\lilyGlyph{rests.M1neomensural}}\kern-1.16pt}}}% vertical bar below center of note head (original distance) 
\newcommand{\ptt}[1]{\kern-4pt\pt {#1}\kern4pt}% point closer to note head (original distance is defined for larger \nq)
%
\newcommand{\dsbrm}{\zcharnote{0}{\hbsk\begin{tikzpicture}%
\useasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (0.15,0.15);%
\node at (0,0) {};
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.27,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
\draw[line width=0.5pt,draw=black] (0.35,-0.01) -- ++(0,0.525); %
%\draw[red] (current bounding box.south west) rectangle (current bounding box.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}}}% works, but quite complicated if there is an existing symbol in amssymb
%
\newcommand{\caeg}{\charnote{b}{\kern-4.1pt$\A\textbf\shortmid$\kern4.1pt}\hbsk}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\dsbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid\hspace{-0.125cm}\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbr}{\notes\zcharnote M{\kern-1.1pt$\A\textbf\mid$\kern1.1pt}\hbsk\en}% see differences in spacing
%
\newcommand{\sbre}{\zcharnote O{\kern-1.6pt$\A\textbf\mid$}}% see differences in spacing
%
\startpiece%
\A\assignlyrics{1}{Letras}%
\addspace{0.5\afterruleskip}%
\notes\squ{MM}\podatus{N}{a}\clivis{a}{N}\squ{a}\squ{_b}\clivis{a}{N}\usttt a\clivis{a}{N}\caeg%
\squ{MMMN}\ptt N\squ{N}\dsbrm\en%\setdoublebar\bar%
%%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\notes\sk\sk\en\zalaligne% there is no \alaligne, it is a custos, for which I haven't found a symbol yet (half a \squ mirrored, with stem up)
%
\notes\squ{MM}\podatus{N}{a}\clivis{a}{N}\squ{a}\squ{_b}\clivis{a}{N}\usttt a\clivis{a}{N}\caeg%
\squ{MMN}\ptt N\squ{N}\dsbrm\en\notes\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\en%%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{MM}\podatus{N}{a}\clivis{a}{N}\squ{a}\squ{_b}\clivis{a}{N}\usttt a\clivis{a}{N}\caeg%
\squ{MMN}\ptt N\squ{N}\dsbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\notes\sk\sk\sk\sk\en\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{MNM}\podatus{N}{a}\squ{aM}\clivis{N}{M}\usttt K\clivis{K}{J}%
\squ{NaN}\ptt M\squ{M}\dsbrm\en%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\notes\sk\sk\sk\sk\sk\en\zalaligne%
%
\notes\squ{MNM}\podatus{N}{a}\squ{aM}\clivis{N}{M}\usttt K\clivis{K}{J}%
\squ{N}\tristropha{N}{a}{N}\Porrectus{M}{K}{M}\ptt M\squ{M}\dsbrm\en\notes\sk\sk\sk\sk\en%%\shortbarrules\bar%\zapostropha{L}
\zstoppiece
%\nolyr%
%\lyricsoff%
\end{music}
\end{document}

The output is as follow:

